# I need to use http://www.vtk.org/ 3D models on my Django application with Mezzanine

Tags: javascript, django, vtk, mezzanine

I have django 1.5.1 with Mezzanine installed and an app running. I want to create a 3D graph which is interactive on my app, which is basically from VTK software. Is their any options to do that